# how to hide domain name?

Tags: python, django, url

I have developed a web interface for a system in django, which is running on my institution server (abc.edu). So the web address for the interface is http://def.abc.edu:8000/mysystem.

I am going to submit a paper about the system in a double blind conference (reviewers should not know which institution I am from). SO, I can not put the link http://def.abc.edu:8000/mysystem in my paper, I have to hide the domain name. Is there a way to do that in django, or in any other way? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Purchase another domain name and make it an alias to `def.abc.edu`? Technically the reviewers could still find the "real" domain name (e.g., by using `host`) but they'd have to go out of their way. Barring that, you could put it on a commercial server (e.g., Heroku) that's not associated with your institution.

Comment: This is a web server issue, not a web framework issue.  As mipadi suggests, you need to have a registered domain to serve your site from.  You can configure the URL display using the web server on your host.

Comment: Just a (simple) thought - Create a New Site in django, and copy over all the url patterns, and give it a neutral domain

Comment: I thought of a rather easy solution, which is to use ip address of the web server, instead of the domain name (def.abc.edu). technically you will still be able to see the server loation through a reverseip process, but i don't think that would be counted as a disqalification. I have mailed program committee with this solution and waiting for the reply. thanks for all helps, i might incorporate them if this plan fails.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, this is not done using Django but using a DNS. The reason is simple: when you type an address in the URL bar of your browser, it asks a DNS to which IP does the domain of the URL correspond, which Django (or any other web framework) is oblivious of. Changing your address in Django will only change the URL on links which will become invalid.

Providing directly the IP of your server, as stated in the comments, won't provide any protection of any kind because universities IP addresses ranges are well known. Finding from which university a given IP comes from is easy.

The easiest way to achieve your need would be to get (for free or purchase) a DNS which redirects to your address. Dyndns.org, noip.com and similar DNS service providers gives you some features such as embedding your website in a frame to hide its address from the URL and similar tricks. Most of these tricks are pretty easy to deceive and discover the origin URL or address, though.

You may also host your project on another server, outside your university. Depending on the requirements of your web interface, some hosts may host you for free.